# Having single DAO parent class in an EJB application

Tags: java

I have the following `DAOParent` class that I use to put connect/disconnect code in one place. Each `DAO` class in the application is an `EJB` that extends `DAOParent` (note that I don't use `JPA`):

```
public class DAOParent {

    private InitialContext context = null;
    private DataSource ds = null;
    private Connection conn = null;

    protected Connection getConnFromPool(String pool) throws DAOException { 

        try {
            context = new InitialContext();
            ds = (DataSource)context.lookup(pool);
            conn = ds.getConnection();
            return conn;
        } 
        catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new DAOException(e.getMessage());
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DAOException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    protected void releaseConn() {
        try {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {}

        try {
            if (context != null)
                context.close();
        } 
        catch (NamingException e) {}
    }
}
```

And the `DAO` class:

```
@Stateless
public class DAOChild extends DAOParent {

    public void someMethod() throws DAOException {

        Connection conn = getConnFromPool("some/jndi/path");

        try {

            // use the connection
        } 
        finally {
            releaseConn();
        }
    }
}
```

The `DAOChild` class is then injected in an `EJB` to access the data.

Questions: (1) is there a problem with this approach? (2) If I have `DAOChild1` and `DAOChild2` injected in the same `EJB`, is there a conflict in the connection lookup?

I run this on Wildfly 14 application server/container.